# Determine jQuery Mobile inline tab top

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I'm using this jQuery Mobile inline tabs widget:

https://github.com/kryops/jqm-inlinetabs

And it renders the HTML I have thus:

```
<div id="main_tabs" data-role="inlinetabs" data-mini="true">
    <ul class="ui-inlinetabs-bar ui-corner-all ui-mini">
        <li role="button" style="width: 90px;" data-tab="1" class="tab-list-item ui-btn ui-btn-inline ui-mini ui-corner-all ui-inlinetabs-tab ui-btn-active">Test</li>
        <li role="button" style="width: 90px;" data-tab="2" class="tab-list-item ui-btn ui-btn-inline ui-mini ui-corner-all ui-inlinetabs-tab">Again</li>
    </ul>
    <div class="ui-inlinetabs-container">
        <div style="display: block; height: 500px;" data-tab="1" class="tab-content ui-inlinetabs-content">
        </div>
    <div style="display: none;" data-tab="2" class="tab-content ui-inlinetabs-content">
    </div>
</div>
```

..and in FF looks like this:

[image]

I figured to calculate the absolute top of the tab content (i.e. just below the list of tabs), I'd need to do this:

```
$('#main_tabs').find('.ui-inlinetabs-container').offset().top;
```

Except that it returns 0. Any ideas why it wouldn't be working?

Comment: Your code actually looks working. A fiddle would be great

Comment: I provided a fiddle in a question before. I had spent a deal of time creating the fiddle so that it would be easy for others to see the issue. It was downvoted, then closed as "off-topic" when I removed the link to the fiddle and added more detail instead, so forgive me for being discouraged from having a repeat episode.

Comment: We all are here to learn by doing mistakes. Thats how you got a Peer Pressure badge. I tested in http://kryops.de/jqm/tabs/demo/ with `$('.ui-inlinetabs-container').offset();` and it works

Comment: @DaveNottage Sorry you had a bad experience with fiddle.  Personally, when I see a fiddle, I usually stop and take notice.  I do encourage as many folks as possible to use it and I use it on all my questions.

Comment: @cforcloud How did you actually test?

Comment: Visit http://kryops.de/jqm/tabs/demo/. Open your [browser's console](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Web_Console) and enter `$('.ui-inlinetabs-container').offset();`. I get `{ top: 269.066650390625, left: 15 }`

Comment: @cforcloud Thanks. Works in that demo page and in my app in the console, but doesn't work in the code in my app :-/

Comment: I should add that in my app I'm creating the tabs dynamically, but it is finding the ui-inlinetabs-container element. Looks like I'll need to dig deeper.

Comment: Sure, dig a little more. Feel free to share the full related code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that I was attempting to read the top value before the page was "ready". (I'm using the page-switching feature of jQM to transition between pages).

The solution was to create the tabs after the page is shown using the pagecontainershow event, e.g.:

```
$(document).on('pagecontainershow', function() {
    // Determine which page is being shown by using
    //   $.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer('getActivePage')
    // and act on that
});
```

Thanks to everyone for your comments.